# Arcpy problems regarding convertToMSD() Function

Tags: arcpy, msd

I am having trouble getting the ConvertToMSD Function to work. Technically it works, but not in the long run of my script.

I use the converttomsd function to create an msd. I then publish this msd as a web service. However, the webservice does not show the map. But.. I can save the mxd to an msd in ArcMap, and then publish from my python script and it works. So the snag seems to be the converttomsd function,

I originally thought it was the publishmsdtoserver function, but I was wrong. Any ideas..... I can provide my code if necessary.

Comment: do you need to run a validate in py first? I know that if you run create msd on it's own in arcmap it requires the validate first. Just a shot

Comment: what do you mean validate?

Comment: prior to creating an msd in arcmap you should alway see the validate window come up. this shows the requirements for creation. All services have a required layer description and must pass the other requirements. You may see some warnings and messages like data not using direct connection.

Comment: Compare the contents of the MSDs (the one generated in ArcPy and the one generated in ArcMap) and see if there is a difference.  The MSD is a zip file.  Unzip it to see the contents.

Comment: If you can provide a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that would be helpful.